# Pass interface type to c# in Powershell script?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, reflection, scripting

I have a C# library that I'm trying to script against where one of the most important calls has the following method signature:

```
DoThing(IDictionary<int, IList<int>> dict)
```

I need to write a powershell script that constructs an object to be passed in.  I have written powershell to construct the same thing, but with concrete classes:

```
$myArg= New-Object 'Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int, Collections.Generic.List[int]]'
$list = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[int]'

$myArg.Add(7, $list)

[PowershellReflectionTest.ReflectionTester]::DoThing($myArg)
```

However, this is effectively creating a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` object, which is (for some reason; I don't know why) incompatible with `IDictionary<int, IList<int>>`.

How can I create a compatible type in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$myArg= New-Object 'Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int, Collections.Generic.IList[int]]'
$list = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[int]'
```

In short, this changes the Dictionary's `TValue` to be an `IList<int>` as expected by your C# library.

The list itself is not declared as an interface however.

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I didn't think to try that.  I assumed because there's no strong left-side typing in powershell that it wouldn't be enough or something.